# MongoDB Aggregation - How to keep only docs that has related value in foreign collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In the `lookup` part in the `aggregate` method, how can I keep only documents that have a value in the foreign collection?

For instance, I have this collection `users`:

```
[
    { _id: 1, name: 'John', basketId: 4 },
    { _id: 2, name: 'mari', basketId: 9 },
    { _id: 3, name: 'tedd', basketId: 32 },
    { _id: 4, name: 'sara', basketId: 14 },
    { _id: 5, name: 'jane', basketId: 3 },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

And another collection named `baskets`

```
[
    { _id: 1, items: 0 },
    { _id: 2, items: 2 },
    { _id: 3, items: 0 },
    { _id: 4, items: 0 },
    { _id: 5, items: 7 },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Now if I want to get users with basket items greater than 0, I use `aggregate` and `lookup`:

```
UserModel.aggregate([
  { $lookup:
      {
        from: 'baskets',
        localField: 'basketId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        pipeline: [{ $match: { items: { $gt: 0 } } }],
        as: 'basket'
      }
  }
])
```

It brings up ALL users with their basket data. For those users whose basket items are 0, it shows `basket: []`.

But I need to get ONLY users that have basket items greater than 0. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't place the `$match` stage in the pipeline of `$lookup`. As what it did is filter the documents to be returned in the `basket` array.

Instead, you need a `$match` stage to filter the documents by comparing the first document's `items` value in the `basket` array.

```
UserModel.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "baskets",
      localField: "basketId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "basket"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $first: "$basket.items"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gWTep_vC65P)

---

The question is ambiguous. You may look for the below query as well (but would return the same result as *Demo 1*):

```
UserModel.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "baskets",
      localField: "basketId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            items: {
              $gt: 0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "basket"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: "$basket"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Or check is not an empty array

```
{
  $ne: [
    "$basket",
    []
  ]
}
```

[Demo 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_uD83Zs9XYp)

Comment: Problem solved. I didn't know it matters where to place the `$match` operator, and I can use multiple `$match` operators! Thanks man.